# Extension of the operator diag(·) in a Hilbert space of functions

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $X\in \mathbb{R}^{qxq}$ be a positive-symmetric matrix and let diag$(X)$ a diagonal matrix with the same diagonal elements as $X$. Is there an operator that works as diag$(·)$ for a symmetric, positive-definite and bounded operator in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space of functions?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that to see a matrix as an operator, you need to fix an orthonormal basis.

So, if you fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ of $H$, you can define your diagonal operator by
$$
D(T)e_n=\langle Te_n,e_n\rangle\,e_n.
$$
This is the same as saying that
$$
D(T)=\sum_k E_kTE_k,
$$
where $E_k$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathbb C e_n$.

You can do the above for each orthonormal basis, and you will get different operators; there is no proviledged orthonormal basis on a general Hilbert space.

The operator $D$ is an example of a *conditional expectation*. One can generalize the above setup to consider a maximal abelian subalgebra $A$  of $B(H)$, and consider $D:B(H)\to A$ to be a norm-one projection. This setup is more general than the previous one because not every maximal abelian subalgebra is atomic (i.e., coming from an orthonormal basis).

Comment: Hello, that is fantastic @Martin Argerami I also found this https://www.jstor.org/stable/44237679?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents. So $E_k$ is the resolution of the identity and a condition for $D$ to exists is boundedness, so that the sequence generated by the inner product has a finite sum, right?

Comment: If you have a pairwise orthogonal sequence of projections $\{P_k\}$, the sum $\sum_kP_kTP_k$ always converges in the strong operator topology. As for the basis in ran$(T)$, not sure what you are aiming for, as the $D$ is a function that evaluates on operators so it should be defined on all $T$.

Comment: Yes, sure. Many thanks, Professor @Martin Argerami